# How to get the inner html value

Tags: javascript

```
<span style="color: red"> advertising cctv/bust</span>
<span style="color: red">a</span>tion
```

how to get the value from this text

I used replace function but it removing only once and it ignoring second one

how can i do this one

Comment: What exactly is your input? Do you have a string, or are you parsing the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

[InnerHTML In JavaScript](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/innerhtml_in_javascript.cfm)

[Changing Text with innerHTML](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php)

Comment: <span style="color: red"> advertising cctv/bust</span><span style="color: red">a</span>tion
how to get the value from this text
I used replace function but it removing only once and it ignoring second one
how can i do this on