# How to get the inner html value

Tags: javascript

```
var str_f = document.getElementById("" + j + "").innerHTML;

<p>
  <span style="color: red">advertising cctv/bust</span>
  <span style="color: red">a</span>tion
</p>
```

how can i get the value

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @Sampath. Please consider updating your question with more information and specifics about what exactly you're trying to do. Do you want the `innerHTML` value of the paragraph, one or both of the spans, or something else?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying a little, I can't parse your question.

Comment: Which value do you want exactly? Your code is not stating what do you want

Comment: Didnt you just ask this earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321245/how-to-get-the-inner-html-value Please consider editing your earlier question if you want to make additions to it. Looks like a dupe to me

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the innerHTML of the `<p>` tag then give it an id and then use the following code

```
<p id="para1"><span style="color: red"> advertising cctv/bust</span><span style="color: red">a</span>tion </p>


document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML;
```

If you want to get text content inside the element then you can use

```
var elem = document.getElementById("para1");
var elementText = x.innerText || x.textContent
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work, your doing a getElementById but you don't have any elements with Id's...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to get the innerHTML value of any tag, you either need that tag to have its 'id' property or 'name' property set.

Then you can respectively use the 'document.getElementById(yourTagIdValue).innerHTML' or 'document.getElementByName(yourTagNameValue).innerHTML' to fetch the value of the required tag.

For eg.

Sampath

So, you can get the innerHTML of this  tag as follows:

document.getElementById("lblName").innerHTML.

Also, do kindly note that there is a difference for HTML tags for which you can use the 'innerHTML' property and 'value' property.

Regards,
Mahendra Liya.

Comment: Its not `document.getElementByName', its `document.getElementsByName`. This will return an array of elements with the name specified.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mention the ID anywhere in the Tags so you cannot use getElementsById.

You can get the innerHTML of the < p > by using [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName).

Here is how we use it.
Syndtax: 
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(name);

In your case:

var pElement = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

var pElementHtml = pElement.innerHTML;

if you need just the text, you can do

var pElementText = pElement.innerText || pElement.textContent;

Hope its useful for someone.

-Sijan